# Writing a union operation in prolog for multisets

Tags: prolog, multiset

In the prolog there is a standard way to define union of two sets 
But I want to write union function for multisets. That would mean if first set has [1,2] and 
second has [2,3] then the output should be [1,2,2,3]. 
How do I go about writing such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no type *Set* in Prolog. What you are referencing are just lists. The `union` predicate combines two lists with *assumed* unique elements to a new list where the elements are again unique. The order does not matter in a set. You see that when you pass a non-ordered/non-set list.

```
% both ordered, but result is not
?- union([1, 2, 5, 6], [3, 4, 7, 8], S).
S = [1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8].

% sets, not ordered
?- union([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 4, 5], S).
S = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5].

% multisets, not ordered
?- union([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 4, 5, 5], S).
S = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5].
```

To create a multiset, i.e. keep all elements in the set union, you can just combine the lists, while ordering them as you please. Formally, a multiset is not ordered as well, so if sorting does not matter, you can just append the second list to the first, which also works with your example:

```
?- append([1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], S).
S = [1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5].

?- append([1, 2], [2, 3], S).
S = [1, 2, 2, 3].
```

If you can assume the lists to be ordered and you want that to be the case in the result, you can just merge them, which keeps the order:

```
?- merge([1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], S).
S = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5].
```

If you can not assume the lists to be sorted, but you want to have the result sorted, you can also take care of the sorting yourself, e.g. with msort:

```
?- append([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 4, 5, 5], S), msort(S, S1).
S = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5],
S1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5].
```

There are also more sorting predicates around, and if it's more complicated you can write one yourself, too.

Comment: I got the union working. I need some help for subset - `subset([],_).
subset([X|L],Set):-
member(X,Set),subset(L,Set).` This is the code for normal subset, but now the set is a multiset and so instead of checking subset(L,Set) I need to remove the X from Set and then check if L is a subset of Set. How to do that in prolog

Comment: I don't fully understand how that would make it a multiset check. But you can use ```delete (Set, X, NewSet)``` to create a new set without ```X```.

Comment: “The `union` predicate combines two lists with assumed ordered unique elements” I believe your examples show that `union` assumes elements to be unique in each list, but not to be ordered, am I wrong? If it assumed lists to be sorted, you would get `[1, 2, 3, 2, …]` instead of  `[1, 3, 2, …]`.

Comment: @Maëlan You are correct, I confused it with ```ord_union```. Will correct the answer.

Comment: Example of union that I want to implement - `A = {a; a; b; b; b; c; d; d}; B = {b; b; c; c; c; d; d; e} A U B = {a; a; b; b; b; c; c; c; d; d; e}`  all elements maximum count . The order of elements is not important in the output

Comment: There is a weird thing. When the ouput is long prolog displays it like - `X = [a, a, b, b, b, c, d, d, b|...].` How to see the full output.

Comment: @bittu The interpreter caps the lists when they get too long. you can add ```,write(X)``` if you really have them printed. As for your new example: I don't think you would call that a multiset union. What you want to have is a combined list, which contains the maximum number of each individual value contained in both lists. Maybe you want to start a new question with that to rephrase.